# Networking on Android NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, networking

I have a class called ServerHelper which extends Thread
In

```
@Override
public void run
InetAddress svrAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
socket = new Socket(svrAddr, SERVERPORT);
```

ServerHelper is singleton because I want to use the same socket connection between the different activities. On the first Activity I call

```
ServerActivity.getInstance().run();
```

Then I get the exception. I checked the Debug pane and the run() is running on the Main thread. Why is that?

Surely if it extends Thread it should automatically kick of on a new thread right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start threads with `start()`. `run()` just runs the contained runnable in the current thread.

Comment: Thanks :) Works now :) Rookie mistake

Comment: No shame there. Even experienced developers get bitten by `thread.run()` at times :)